# Give my android app a widget option

Tags: android, widget

My users are asking me to make one of my apps into a widget. Is there a way to ask if they want a widget in app and then add the widget to their home screen? I am having a tough time finding this on Google.

Edit:
Is there add a widget option to an existing app or do I have to have to write a whole new program?

Comment: A widget for the homescreen is called 'app widget'. That might make searching Google a lot easier :)

Answer (score 1):

If you provide a home screen widget, it is up to the user to add it to his home screen. A very basic reason why you can't and shouldn't add programmatically a widget to the home screen is that you should select an empty space (if it is available), and it could not even ever being noticed by the user.

Update: there is absolutely no need to write a new program, you can (and should) implement all the widget code and requirements in the same package. This is the basic guide for widgets: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: I was looking for a way to have them add it, I guess I wasn't clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

By "have them add it" do you mean

1.Tell the user that there is a widget and they can add it to the home screen?

this can easily  be done by adding a note in your applications description in the Google play store or with the help of a toast message some where inside your application.

```
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " A widget is available and can be added"  ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).long();
```

2 Add a widget to the home screen from within the your application ?

This is , as far as I am aware, is not possible.

hope this answers your question.